# Do we have any tool which can give me size of functions which are in .wasm file

Tags: emscripten, webassembly

I have a .wasm file which has lots of mangled functions[which I Knew after converting it into .txt file using wasm-dis.ex]. How can I know the size of each function? Do we have any tool which can help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a tool called [Twiggy](https://github.com/rustwasm/twiggy) which creates call graphs and allows you to analyse the size of functions etc ...

Comment: I encountered with this 
thread 'main' panicked at 'assertion failed: index < u32::MAX as usize'

 C:\Users\kumarpr.cargo\bin>twiggy monos C:\TEMP\AcFabricBackend.wasm
 thread 'main' panicked at 'assertion failed: index < u32::MAX as usize', C:\Users\kumarpr.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\twiggy-ir-0.2.0./ir.rs:414:9
 stack backtrace:
 0: 
 1: 
 2: 
 3: 
 4: 
 5: 
 6: 
 7: 
 8: 
 9: 
 10: 
 11: 
 12: 
 13: 
 14: 
 15: 
 16: 
 17: 
 18: BaseThreadInitThunk
 19: RtlUserThreadStart